# linter error on `with` vs simple variable assignment (neo4j driver)

Tags: python, with-statement, neo4j-python-driver

This works as documented:

```
  with driver.session() as session:
```

but my linter throws an error on this:

```
  session = driver.session()

  > Assigning result of a function call, where the function has no returnpylint(assignment-from-no-return)
```

[image]

I thought that [`with`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/) was just a syntax sugar to handle closing handles etc.

Note that the code itself will run but the linter errors are really distracting.
Is there a way to fix the original codes such that

I'm trying to get a session object to use for multiple transactions (or the lifetime of my app)

https://neo4j.com/docs/api/python-driver/current/driver.html#neo4j.Driver.session

source is here
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver

Comment: Have you actually checked if the linter is correct, here? I think it's just probably wrong.

Comment: the code works, so I assume the linter is wrong, but not sure how to dig deeper. 
I did get a hint about how to turn off linting for one line: `# noinspection INSPECTION_NAME`

Comment: the JS version looks exactly like my desired python code https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/1.7/sessions-transactions/